# jquery carousel - can't seem to get previous image sliding in

Tags: jquery, carousel

Please the the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Snp7F/2/

Clicking the next button works perfectly (current image slides left and next image slides in), however when I click the previous button it does work however it's not sliding in the previous image in the set.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help me out?

Here is the code:

```
$.carousel = function(obj){
var width = $(obj).find('ul').find("li:first").outerWidth();

$(obj).find('.slider_prev').click(function() {
   if($(obj).find('li').length > 1) {
       $(obj).find('ul').animate({marginLeft:326},750,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
       })
   }               
   return false;
});
$(obj).find('.slider_next').click(function() {
   if($(obj).find('li').length > 1) {
        $(obj).find('ul').animate({marginLeft:-326},750,function(){
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
        })
   }
   return false;
}); 
}
$.carousel('#slider_1');​
```

Answer (score 0):

At any given time, there should be an image left **and** right of the one you're actually viewing. I would update the logic to include a third `li`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue. I did however find a fix with another simple gallery: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/